# state processing function not working as expected

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm working on state processing function where im keying on an ID and would like to hold a state for like 60 secs.

```
DataStream<String> keyedStream = stream.keyBy(Events::getAnonymousId)
                .process(new KeyedProcessingWithCallBack(Long.parseLong(parameters.get("ttl"))))
                .uid("keyed-processing");

        keyedStream.sinkTo(sink(parameters))
                .uid("kafka-sink");
```

```
public class KeyedProcessingWithCallBack extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, Events, String> {
    ValueState<Boolean> anonymousIdHasBeenSeen;

    private final long stateTtl;

    public KeyedProcessingWithCallBack(long stateTtl) {
        this.stateTtl = stateTtl;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        ValueStateDescriptor<Boolean> desc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("anonymousIdHasBeenSeen", Types.BOOLEAN);
        // defines the time the state has to be stored in the state backend before it is auto cleared
        anonymousIdHasBeenSeen = getRuntimeContext().getState(desc);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(EngagerEvents value, KeyedProcessFunction<String, Events, String>.Context ctx, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {

        if (anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.value() == null) {
            System.out.println("Value is NULL : " +value.getAnonymousId());
            // key is not available in the state
            anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.update(true);
            System.out.println("TIMER START TIME: " +ctx.timestamp());
            ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(ctx.timestamp() + (stateTtl * 1000));
            out.collect(value.getEventString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<String> out)
            throws Exception {
        // triggers after ttl has passed
        System.out.println("Call back triggered : time : " +timestamp + " value : " +anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.value());
        if (anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.value()) {
            anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.clear();
        }
    }
```

I have registered a timer to clear value from state. however as per my logs it is triggering correctly. but my process element is accepting the value for the same key before even it is cleared in the call back.

Expect data in the output topic are separated by a minute gap, but is not.[image]

Can someone point out the mistake in my implementation here. I'm spanning multiple threads to pump request at the same time.

Comment: It's not clear that the timestamps you are comparing are all coming from the same machine.

Comment: thank you for your reponse. they are all coming from the same machine(Im testing on my mac). One thing what I'm not understanding is, out.collect is emitting records even though there is a key for that state(60 secs timer). my out kafka topic has received messages for the same key with no 1 minute has passed between them.